# Laravel would randomly try to access a non existent symlink

Tags: php, linux, laravel, nginx, continuous-integration

First, allow me to explain how my deployment works:

1. Get latest code and put into a temporary directory
2. Get the current timestamp in epoch format and store in a variable
3. Create a new directory with the name of the timestamp and move latest code into the directory
4. Create symlinks to `vendor` and `storage` directories. Also create a symlink for `.env`
5. Go inside the timestamp directory and run a few Composer and Laravel commands
6. Symlink the timestamp to directory called **current** which will be accessed by Nginx
7. Set correct ownership and permission
8. Restart PHP-FPM and Supervisor
9. Delete old release

Occasionally I would get an error like this:

```
The stream or file "/usr/share/nginx/html/sample_directory/releases/1617243734/storage/logs/laravel-2021-04-07.log" could not be opened in append mode: failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

where `1617243734` is the old timestamp directory which doesn't exist anymore.

Does anyone know the reason for this issue?

Below is the deployment file:

```
#!/bin/sh

########################################
# Get current timestamp in epoch format
########################################
timestamp=$(date +%s)

##############################################################################
# Create new directory based on timestamp and move code into timestamp folder
##############################################################################
mkdir /usr/share/nginx/html/sample_directory/releases/$timestamp
mv /usr/share/nginx/html/sample_directory/temp/* /usr/share/nginx/html/sample_directory/releases/$timestamp/
mv /usr/share/nginx/html/sample_directory/temp/.editorconfig /usr/share/nginx/html/sample_directory/releases/$timestamp/
mv /usr/share/nginx/html/sample_directory/temp/.git /usr/share/nginx/html/sample_directory/releases/$timestamp/
mv /usr/share/nginx/html/sample_directory/temp/.gitattributes /usr/share/nginx/html/sample_directory/releases/$timestamp/
mv /usr/share/nginx/html/sample_directory/temp/.idea /usr/share/nginx/html/sample_directory/releases/$timestamp/
mv /usr/share/nginx/html/sample_directory/temp/.styleci.yml /usr/share/nginx/html/sample_directory/releases/$timestamp/
mv /usr/share/nginx/html/sample_directory/temp/.gitignore /usr/share/nginx/html/sample_directory/releases/$timestamp/

#############################################################################
# Create symlinks to vendor & storage directories. Also symlink to .env file
#############################################################################
rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/sample_directory/releases/$timestamp/storage
ln -s /usr/share/nginx/html/sample_directory/shared/storage /usr/share/nginx/html/sample_directory/releases/$timestamp/ 
ln -s /usr/share/nginx/html/sample_directory/shared/vendor /usr/share/nginx/html/sample_directory/releases/$timestamp/
ln -s /usr/share/nginx/html/sample_directory/shared/.env /usr/share/nginx/html/sample_directory/releases/$timestamp/

#####################################
# Run composer install
#####################################
cd /usr/share/nginx/html/sample_directory/releases/$timestamp
composer install

##############################
# Run needed Laravel commands
##############################
php artisan migrate
php artisan config:cache
composer dump-autoload
php artisan config:cache

############################################
# Symlink current to the new release directory
############################################
rm -r /usr/share/nginx/html/sample_directory/current
ln -sv /usr/share/nginx/html/sample_directory/releases/$timestamp /usr/share/nginx/html/sample_directory/current

##################################
# Change permission and ownership
##################################
chown -R nginx:nginx /usr/share/nginx/html/sample_directory
find /usr/share/nginx/html/sample_directory -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
find /usr/share/nginx/html/sample_directory -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;

##############
# Restart FPM
##############
systemctl restart php-fpm

####################
# Restart supervisor
####################
supervisorctl restart all

############################
# Keep only current release
############################
cd /usr/share/nginx/html/sample_directory/releases
ls -1t | tail -n +2 | xargs rm -rf
```

Comment: since you mentionned a supervisor in your deployment, did you restart the queue worked each time you redeploy ? because that will leaves a process that has the previous path in memory running. Restarting the supervisor doesnt restart the queue process.

Comment: @N69S Thanks for your comment. It could very well be the cause. I'll implement your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @N69S for the comment. Substituting `supervisorctl restart all` with `php artisan queue:restart` seems to stop the error from occurring.